# A close button for Lightbox_me

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I've googled for a script for a close button for Lightbox_me, however all I've been able to find are scripts for bare-bones lightboxes.

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.lightbox_me = function (options) {

        return this.each(function () {

            var
            opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.lightbox_me.defaults, options),
                $overlay = $(),
                $self = $(this),
                $iframe = $('<iframe id="foo" style="z-index: ' + (opts.zIndex + 1) + ';border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; filter: mask();"/>');

            if (opts.showOverlay) {
                //check if there's an existing overlay, if so, make subequent ones clear
                var $currentOverlays = $(".js_lb_overlay:visible");
                if ($currentOverlays.length > 0) {
                    $overlay = $('<div class="lb_overlay_clear js_lb_overlay"/>');
                } else {
                    $overlay = $('<div class="' + opts.classPrefix + '_overlay js_lb_overlay"/>');
                }
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               DOM Building
            ---------------------------------------------------- */
            $('body').append($self.hide()).append($overlay);

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Overlay CSS stuffs
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

            // set css of the overlay
            if (opts.showOverlay) {
                setOverlayHeight(); // pulled this into a function because it is called on window resize.
                $overlay.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: '100%',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 2),
                    display: 'none'
                });
                if (!$overlay.hasClass('lb_overlay_clear')) {
                    $overlay.css(opts.overlayCSS);
                }
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Animate it in.
            ---------------------------------------------------- */
            //
            if (opts.showOverlay) {
                $overlay.fadeIn(opts.overlaySpeed, function () {
                    setSelfPosition();
                    $self[opts.appearEffect](opts.lightboxSpeed, function () {
                        setOverlayHeight();
                        setSelfPosition();
                        opts.onLoad()
                    });
                });
            } else {
                setSelfPosition();
                $self[opts.appearEffect](opts.lightboxSpeed, function () {
                    opts.onLoad()
                });
            }

            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Hide parent if parent specified (parentLightbox should be jquery reference to any parent lightbox)
            ---------------------------------------------------- */
            if (opts.parentLightbox) {
                opts.parentLightbox.fadeOut(200);
            }


            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Bind Events
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

            $(window).resize(setOverlayHeight)
                .resize(setSelfPosition)
                .scroll(setSelfPosition);

            $(window).bind('keyup.lightbox_me', observeKeyPress);

            if (opts.closeClick) {
                $overlay.click(function (e) {
                    closeLightbox();
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            }
            $self.delegate(opts.closeSelector, "click", function (e) {
                closeLightbox();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $self.bind('close', closeLightbox);
            $self.bind('reposition', setSelfPosition);



            /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


            /*----------------------------------------------------
               Private Functions
            ---------------------------------------------------- */

            /* Remove or hide all elements */
            function closeLightbox() {
                var s = $self[0].style;
                if (opts.destroyOnClose) {
                    $self.add($overlay).remove();
                } else {
                    $self.add($overlay).hide();
                }

                //show the hidden parent lightbox
                if (opts.parentLightbox) {
                    opts.parentLightbox.fadeIn(200);
                }
                if (opts.preventScroll) {
                    $('body').css('overflow', '');
                }
                $iframe.remove();

                // clean up events.
                $self.undelegate(opts.closeSelector, "click");
                $self.unbind('close', closeLightbox);
                $self.unbind('repositon', setSelfPosition);

                $(window).unbind('resize', setOverlayHeight);
                $(window).unbind('resize', setSelfPosition);
                $(window).unbind('scroll', setSelfPosition);
                $(window).unbind('keyup.lightbox_me');
                opts.onClose();
            }


            /* Function to bind to the window to observe the escape/enter key press */
            function observeKeyPress(e) {
                if ((e.keyCode == 27 || (e.DOM_VK_ESCAPE == 27 && e.which == 0)) && opts.closeEsc) closeLightbox();
            }


            /* Set the height of the overlay
                    : if the document height is taller than the window, then set the overlay height to the document height.
                    : otherwise, just set overlay height: 100%
            */
            function setOverlayHeight() {
                if ($(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $overlay.css({
                        height: $(document).height() + 'px'
                    });
                    $iframe.css({
                        height: $(document).height() + 'px'
                    });
                } else {
                    $overlay.css({
                        height: '100%'
                    });
                }
            }


            /* Set the position of the modal'd window ($self)
                    : if $self is taller than the window, then make it absolutely positioned
                    : otherwise fixed
            */
            function setSelfPosition() {
                var s = $self[0].style;

                // reset CSS so width is re-calculated for margin-left CSS
                $self.css({
                    left: '50%',
                    marginLeft: ($self.outerWidth() / 2) * -1,
                    zIndex: (opts.zIndex + 3)
                });


                /* we have to get a little fancy when dealing with height, because lightbox_me
                    is just so fancy.
                 */

                // if the height of $self is bigger than the window and self isn't already position absolute
                if (($self.height() + 80 >= $(window).height()) && ($self.css('position') != 'absolute')) {

                    // we are going to make it positioned where the user can see it, but they can still scroll
                    // so the top offset is based on the user's scroll position.
                    var topOffset = $(document).scrollTop() + 40;
                    $self.css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: topOffset + 'px',
                        marginTop: 0
                    })
                } else if ($self.height() + 80 < $(window).height()) {
                    //if the height is less than the window height, then we're gonna make this thing position: fixed.
                    if (opts.centered) {
                        $self.css({
                            position: 'fixed',
                            top: '50%',
                            marginTop: ($self.outerHeight() / 2) * -1
                        })
                    } else {
                        $self.css({
                            position: 'fixed'
                        }).css(opts.modalCSS);
                    }
                    if (opts.preventScroll) {
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    }
                }
            }

        });



    };

    $.fn.lightbox_me.defaults = {

        // animation
        appearEffect: "fadeIn",
        appearEase: "",
        overlaySpeed: 250,
        lightboxSpeed: 300,

        // close
        closeSelector: ".close",
        closeClick: true,
        closeEsc: true,

        // behavior
        destroyOnClose: false,
        showOverlay: true,
        parentLightbox: false,
        preventScroll: false,

        // callbacks
        onLoad: function () {},
        onClose: function () {},

        // style
        classPrefix: 'lb',
        zIndex: 999,
        centered: true,
        modalCSS: {
            top: '100px'
        },
        overlayCSS: {
            background: 'black',
            opacity: .3
        }
    }

    $('.trigger').click(function (e) {
        $('.lightbox').lightbox_me();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[This is the jsfiddle with the script for Lightbox_me.](http://jsfiddle.net/hethesavior/zn2hg7L8/)

I tried to incorporate the close-button scripts for the bare-bones lightboxes into Lightbox_me, but I simply don't know where to start. Would I have to format a close button onto each of the lightboxed divs individually and simply bind `closeLightbox();`? Or is there a more elegant way to do it involving only the script?

Comment: If you're using jquery, you have the option of jquery-ui which has the dialog module and can be found here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/.  I've not used lightbox_me before, but it looks to be fairly bare bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the script has these defined:

```
$.fn.lightbox_me.defaults = {

    // animation
    appearEffect: "fadeIn",
    appearEase: "",
    overlaySpeed: 250,
    lightboxSpeed: 300,

    // close
    closeSelector: ".close",
    closeClick: true,
    closeEsc: true,

    // behavior
    destroyOnClose: false,
    showOverlay: true,
    parentLightbox: false,
    preventScroll: false,

    // callbacks
    onLoad: function () {},
    onClose: function () {},

    // style
    classPrefix: 'lb',
    zIndex: 999,
    centered: true,
    modalCSS: {
        top: '100px'
    },
    overlayCSS: {
        background: 'black',
        opacity: .3
    }
}
```

You'll notice in the close section that it defaults to looking for elements with the class "close".

So if you stick a div with that class inside your lightbox, style as you please then it will trigger the close action.

The logic for closing based on the script:

```
if (opts.closeClick) {
    $overlay.click(function (e) {
        closeLightbox();
        e.preventDefault;
    });
}
$self.delegate(opts.closeSelector, "click", function (e) {
    closeLightbox();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This part of the logic informs lightbox_me that if closeClick is true within the list of options passed to it, that it will setup clicks on the overlay to close the lightbox.

As well it will bind current and future elements with the value defined in opts.closeSelector to also initiate the closeLightbox function when clicked.

Simple example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zn2hg7L8/1/

Comment: Thank you so much for the exceptionally quick (and detailed) answer! You don't know how much I appreciate the explanation for closing logic! :) Thank you again! Voted up!